# Error con GAM (Create Table)

Tags: mysql, .net, docker, genexus

### Windows 11
GX 17 U7
mysql 5.7 (en un docker)

¿Alguna idea de porque al hacer el Creater Table del GAM me da este error?

**Nota**: al hacer el create database de la KB lo hace bien.

*error::::*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> Type:GeneXus.Data.GxADODataException.Se ha intentado cargar un
> programa con un formato incorrecto. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
> in: agamgetversion.exe Stack Trace:    en
> GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand.FetchData(IDataReader& dr)    en
> GeneXus.Data.NTier.ADO.ForEachCursor.execute()    en
> GeneXus.Data.NTier.DataStoreProvider.execute(Int32 cursor, Object[]
> parms, Boolean batch)    en
> GeneXus.Data.NTier.DataStoreProvider.execute(Int32 cursor)    en
> GeneXus.Security.API.agamgetversion.S121()    en
> GeneXus.Security.API.agamgetversion.executePrivate()    en
> GeneXus.Security.API.agamgetversion.execute()    en
> GeneXus.Security.API.agamgetversion.executeCmdLine(String[] args)
> en GeneXus.Security.API.agamgetversion.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Los spool en el iis ya tienen la propiedad enable 32 bit = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logre solucionar el problema.**

Fue una suma de cosas...

1. IIS spool debe tener la propiedad enable 32bit = true
2. En mi caso, la dll del driver libmysql.dll, que creo recordar que la instala MySQLDriverCS-n-EasyQueryTools-4.0.1-DotNet2.0.exe, no me funcionó, ya que es antigua y tuve que usar una nueva. Esa dll me da el error **0x8007000B** y copié una versión más nueva.
3. Como recomienda un SAC de GX, copie otras dll a system32 y a una carpeta de la GAM en la kb. La verdad no sé si el resto de la dll que copie influyen en algo.
4. Permisos de firewall (ya sea el de windows u otro, esto a veces da dolores de cabeza si no nos fijamos)
5. Las dll las copie en system32 y en la carpeta de la kb, ejemplo:
   `<ruta kb>\CSharpModel\Library\GAM`

**DLL's que me funcionaron:**
[Descargar Dll's](https://teigps-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/rmunoz_teilab_cl/EXCcAKCstPdEgXT3-DY_J-oBD04AtlivDU8w1peb7E9_IQ?e=D6vLwm)

Answer (score 0):

Tambien logre solucionar un problema de deploy de gxflow en la version 17 parche 11. Dejo como referencia este SAC : https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=43792;;

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).